# how do you check if file exists in a share

Tags: r

I am trying to see if file exists as follows:

linux.csv is like this

```
    servera
    serverb
    serverc
    serverd
```

```
server<-read.csv("C:/linux.csv")
setwd("\\\\share\directory\")

for (i in server) {
  
  print(i)
}
  i<-paste0(i,".sh")
  if(!file.exists(i)){
    print(i)
    print(paste0(i, " does not exists"))
  }
}
```

this does not seem to be working, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`read.csv` returns a data frame. When you do `for (i in dataframe)` it will iterate over columns of the data frame, not rows. But
it looks like you have a single column with 4 rows, so that is the reason it isn't working.

I would suggest using `readLines` instead of `read.csv`, which will return a character vector. The rest of your code should work better then (though you seem to have an extra `}`... be careful your `for` loop doesn't end with a `}` immediately after the first `print()` statement).

Also, all backslashes in R strings need to be doubled, because they are escape characters. So `setwd("\\\\share\directory\")` needs to be `setwd("\\\\share\\directory\\")`. (Or use forward slashes instead.)